# Can you manually add arguments?

Tags: excel, vba

What I am trying to do is

-Get the sums of X, Y, X^2, Y^2 and ( X * Y )

-Get the averages of X, Y and ( X * Y )

-Get the variance of X and the variance of Y

-Get the covariance between X and Y

-Calculate a1 and a0

Everything was going pretty well until now. I have to calculate a Predicted Y(ŷ) for every X by multiplying every X by a1 and then add a0 ( so Y = a1x * a0). So the steps I am missing are the following:

- Calculate the sum of all (ŷ - ȳ) ^ 2
- Calculate the sum of all (y - ȳ) ^ 2
- Divide the first one by the second one.

And make it a function. I have tried to make the code a little clearer, but contrarily to the very unclear one, this one does not work. I just hope it's a little easier to understand. Thanks again!

```
Function Coeff_Correl(x As Range, y As Range) As Double

n = 20


'Input x & y Points
For i = 1 To n
x(i) = Cells(1 + i, 2)
y(i) = Cells(1 + i, 1)
Next i

'Créer les sommes
Somme_X = 0
Somme_Y = 0
Somme_X2 = 0
Somme_Y2 = 0
Somme_XY = 0
For i = 1 To n
Somme_X = Somme_X + x(i)
Somme_Y = Somme_Y + y(i)
Somme_X2 = Somme_X2 + x(i) * x(i)
Somme_Y2 = Somme_Y2 + y(i) * y(i)
Somme_XY = Somme_XY + x(i) * y(i)
Next i




'Calculer les moyennes
ym = Somme_Y / n
xm = Somme_X / n
xym = Somme_XY / n




'Calculer les variances et la covariance
variance_X = Somme_X2 / n - xm ^ 2
variance_y = Somme_Y2 / n - ym ^ 2
covariance_xy = xym - xm * ym




'Calculer a1
a1 = covariance_xy / variance_X



'Calculer a0
a0 = ym - (a1 * xm)



'Calculer le SCE et le SCT
sce = 0
sct = 0
For i = 1 To n
sce = sce + ((x(i) * a1 + a0) - ym) ^ 2
sct = sct + (y(i) - ym) ^ 2
Next i

'Calculer R^2

r2 = sce / sct

End Function
```

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to do. Maybe include your code so people can have a better idea what you are talking about?

Comment: If you have `Sub DoSomething()` and you want it to be a function with two Range arguments, you need to redefine it as `Function DoSomething(ByVal Y As Range, ByVal X as Range) As ReturnType` where `ReturnType` is the data type of the value your function is going to be returning. Note that the role of a *function* is fundamentally very different than that of a *procedure*: a `Sub` doesn't return anything, but a `Function` always returns something (even if only implicitly). Lastly, whether or not a function can work from a worksheet cell depends on exactly what it does and how it does it.

Comment: In other words, there's not enough information in your post about what you're trying to do for us to give you a more specific answer that makes sense and is useful.

Comment: Thank you braX, thank you Mathieu Guindon!

Comment: I did not put the code since I'm not particularly proud of it haha! I've had some trouble looping from a certain step, so I went manually and it's really hard to read. Also, some of the text is in french, but given your name, Mathieu, you might be able to understand. This is it:

Comment: Too many characters. Any way I can get around that?

Comment: Done. Sorry for your eyes and thank you haha!

Comment: I see. It looks like a function might have to be returning the `r2` value, but then there are other outputs, and a `Function` invoked from a worksheet cell can't write to other cells like that. That said, you could probably replace these 40 numbered variables with 2 arrays, or a single 2D array since the data comes from two adjacent worksheet columns. You could leverage `WorksheetFunction.Sum` instead of looping and manually adding them up. You could break up the procedure into one function for each output, each time taking just the inputs needed to produce the output. (and LOL @ `Case Else`!)

Comment: Further edits to better clarify exactly what you intend the function to output wouldn't hurt, but FYI I've voted to reopen regardless. If 2 other people agree, it'll reopen (further editing to clarify puts the odds on your side!).

Comment: Are you sure you aren't reinventing the [`LINEST`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/linest-function-84d7d0d9-6e50-4101-977a-fa7abf772b6d) function?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Okay yes now I can see that this is a huge issue with my first attempt LOL. Now getting two arrays was what I tried to do with the From 1 to i = n function. I'm not very comfortable with those arrays in VBA lol I'll watch a few Youtube videos right after this hahaha! And I've cleared the other outputs from my function so it can focus on only one thing from now on. Is what I am trying to do a little more clear or not even lol?

Comment: @BigBen I got so scared for a moment but it won't return the value I'm looking for so there must be a tiny difference somewhere between both formulas. Actually all I'm trying to do is to get the value given in B5 when you use the Regression Data Analysis Tool lol.

Comment: If you mean R Square, `LINEST` can return that. Do you mean the R Square returned by `LINEST` differed from what your VBA returned? Or from the Regression Data Analysis tool? Adding sample data would be helpful.

Comment: @BigBen Okay you're probably right and I just don't know how to read the LINEST returned value haha! But the truth is it doesn't really matter if it's useful or not. I'm very interested in adding coding and programming as a personal skill and this is just the very first function I have been trying to do. I'm just practicing I'll never use it again after lol!